# Twisted webserver with plain http2 (h2c)

Tags: twisted

Twisted supports http1 + http2.
How to setup a twisted http2 server over TCP (neither ALPN nor protocol-upgrade)?

The server should answer to this query:

```
curl --http2-prior-knowledge http://localhost:8000/
```

Answer (score 2):

Twisted should set up HTTP/2 servers for you auto-magically. Make sure you install twisted's `http2` modules. The simplest way is to use `pip`:

```
pip install -U twisted[http2]
```

However, I've noticed a few times that it doesn't do run the HTTP/2 stuff out of the box. I had to uninstall `h2`, `hyper` and `hyperframe`, then reinstall them.

```
pip uninstall h2 hyperframe hyper
pip install -U twisted[http2]
```

Using a self signed certificate, here's a small `klein` webserver example.

```sh
openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout pass:SuperSecretPassword -out server.key 4096
openssl req -new -key server.key -passin pass:SuperSecretPassword -out server.csr
# Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:localhost
openssl x509 -req -passin pass:SuperSecretPassword -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server_no_pass.key -passin pass:SuperSecretPassword
mv server_no_pass.key server.key
cat server.crt server.key > selfsigned.pem
rm server.crt server.csr server.key
```

```py
from klein import route, run

@route("/")
def hello(req):
    if req.clientproto == b"HTTP/2":
        return "http2"
    return "http1.1"

run(endpoint_description="ssl:8000:privateKey=selfsigned.pem")
```

### Update

While it's not best practice, there's nothing prohibiting you from running HTTP/2 server on a non-TLS connection. I believe most browsers won't support a non-TLS HTTP/2 server though (at least I couldn't get Firefox and Chrome to work with it). Twisted won't work out the box for you either, so that means you'll have to implement your own server. Follow the [twisted example on the hyper-h2 site](https://python-hyper.org/projects/hyper-h2/en/stable/twisted-example.html). Then replace `endpoints.SSL4ServerEndpoint` with `endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint`.

```py
# ...

endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8080, backlog=128)
endpoint.listen(H2Factory(root))
reactor.run()
```

Comment: This runs twisted on top of SSL - not plain TCP

Comment: I don't believe HTTP/2 will run on a non-TLS connection on most browsers, although I could be misquoting. I've made an update to my answer.

Comment: The use case for this is running twisted behind a load balancer, like a cloud environment/Kubernetes cluster with an ingress that performs TLS termination.

Comment: Yes curiously `pip3 install twisted`  actually install twisted but not the required dependencies (h2 , hpack, hyperframe) required.
After performing `pip install -U twisted[http2]` as explained here, the exact same python code starts serving http2.